# How do I see whether a JWT token (OIDC) is an access token or an ID token for Microsoft identity platform?

Tags: azure, security, azure-ad-msal, msal, microsoft-entra-id

Given a JWT token (OIDC) issued by Microsoft identity platform how do I see whether it's an access token or an ID token?

I'm sure that the `scp` (scope) claim will only be present in access tokens, while the `roles` (roles) claim can both be present in access and  ID tokens. But I don't want the check to rely on assumptions

Comment: why does it matter? if the token authenticates, and then process validates then your golden, so if an id token gets sent instead of an access token it will fail as the scopes missing.

Comment: It doesn't matter per se, but AWS Cognito has a claim for specifying the type of token. I sometimes find that useful, especially jwt.io

Comment: i would suspect you could add a custom claim, but I would think its just adding unessesary claims, i mean in thoery you could have different certificates for different tokens then verify against specific public keys. However an Id Token is never going to authenticate/authorize access because it never has scopes, so a simple has scope claim check will tell you. I guess it depends why and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ***@EnenDaveyBoy***, ID token doesn't contain scopes and hence you cannot use ID token to authenticate/authorize API.

- In Azure, there is no predefined claim to know the token type.

For *sample*, I generated tokens via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

The **access token** when decoded in [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/) looks like below:

[image]

- Access tokens are read by the resource server
- Access token is issued by authorization server, and it contains user, application and the resource the token is indented.
- Using this information, it can access resources and the web APIs.
- Client uses to make requests to an API by using access token.

The **ID token** when decoded looks like below:

[image]

- ID tokens are read by the OAuth client.
- The ID token contains the claims or the information of the authenticated user.
- The client application uses the ID token to verify the authenticated user information.

**Reference:**

[ID Token and Access Token: (auth0.com)](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/) by Andrea Chiarelli